# Assigning user capability to read article on Laravel - article based permissions

Tags: php, laravel

Using laravel, what is the best way to give multiple users the ability to read an article?

I'm using an array in the database containing all permissions (based on user_id), like:

```
id | user_id_permission
1  | {1,37,44}
2  | {34}
```

Then I check if current user ID is in the array, in *ArticleController.php* in the *show(Article $id)* function. If it isn't it redirects to the dashboard.

I was wondering if there is another way to design this, using Laravel's gates or any kind of authentication.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is against DB normalization. I wouldn't use such field in your table, but use a relationship table that links N articles with N users.

article_user_access

```
 id_article | id_user 
------------+--------
 1          | 1
 1          | 37
 1          | 44
 2          | 34
```

This will be easier to perform queries to get the list of users that has access to the article X, or the articles that the user Y can access.

This will be easier to maintain, about adding and deleting access rights

Comment: Thank you so much Cid, for opening my eyes to this approach. Much better!